# Conditionals Based On Several Flags

Tags: java, refactoring, dry

I  wish to refactor Java code that looks like this. a,b,c, and d are boolean flags.

```
if(a && b && c && d) doA();
else if (a && b && c && !d) doB();
else if (a && b && !c && d) doC();
else if (!a && !b && c && d) doD();
```

and so on, for all 16 combinations. Is there a better way? I considered a Map with the values as method references but forming the keys remains a mystery.

Comment: This is strange *anyway*, but some more substantial code besides `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` would go a longer way towards working on an ideal solution.  You'd also want to show us the possible combinations and action chains that you have.  It may be long, but if you're looking for a solid solution, us answerers have to have a solid understanding of your problem.

Comment: if there is no side effects, you can use bit masks.

Comment: Thanks @Makoto but the combinations are as I stated: all 16 ways to combine 4 bits. 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, etc. until 1111. There's no reason to type all that out. What happens in the specific method calls associated with each combination, if that's what you mean by "action chains", is not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create function array,

```
public class FunctionTypes {
    public void func() {}
}

  .....

    FunctionTypes[] functions = new FunctionTypes[] {
            new FunctionTypes() { 
                public void func() { f1(); }

                public void f1() {
                    // handle case #1
                } 
            },
            new FunctionTypes() { 
                public void func() { f2(); }

                public void f2() {
                    // handle case #2
                } 
            },
            new FunctionTypes() { 
                public void func() { f3(); }

                public void f3() {
                    // handle case #3
                } 
            },
            new FunctionTypes() { 
                public void func() { f4(); }

                public void f4() {
                    // handle case #4
                } 
            },
            ....
        };

    // invoke case #0
    functions[0].func();  

    // invoke case #1
    functions[1].func();
```

to select index, use bits from a, b, c, d

```
   index = 0;
   index |= a;
   index |= b << 1;
   index |= c << 2;
   index |= d << 3;
```

as if they are counting all 16 cases. Or you can inherit 16 different sub classes from a main class and override a method in each different sub class and select instances of those classes using top class array. Maybe implementing  an interface could be better.

I don't know if java's map has access time O(n*logn) but array access is O(1).